# while loop does not break out

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

Doing an exercise and I can't figure out why my while loop isn't escaping, it keeps saying that the values aren't valid even when only digits are entered. Any ideas?

```js
// 31. Karvonen Heart Rate
var age, restingPulse, targetRate, numCheckAge, numCheckPulse, valid;
    
    valid = false;
    numCheckAge = /^\d+$/.test(age);
    numCheckPulse = /^\d+$/.test(restingPulse);
    
    while(valid === false) {
      age = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your age:"));
      restingPulse = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your resting heart rate:"));
      if(numCheckAge === true && numCheckPulse === true) {
        valid = true;
      } else {
        alert("Sorry. That's not a valid input, please enter numbers.");
      }
    }
    
    for (var i = 0.55; i < 1; i+=0.05){
      targetRate = (((220 - age) - restingPulse) * i) + restingPulse;
      document.write("Intensity: " + Math.round((i * 100)) + "% | Rate: " + Math.round(targetRate) + "<br>");
    }
```

Comment: You need to execute the `test`s on the regexes inside the loop (after `age` and `restingPulse` have been entered).

Comment: Using the debugger would have shown immediately that `numCheckAge` and `numCheckPulse` are set only once, and are not updated later on...

Comment: Also, you could just use `isNaN(age)` instead of regex to check if inputs are a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified and flexified Your code ;)

Check this out:

```js
    
function requireNumericPrompt(text) {
  var value;
  while(true) {
    if(/^\d+$/.test(value = prompt(text))) {
      return value;
    }
    alert("Sorry. Please enter valid (numeric) value.");
  }
}

var age = parseInt(requireNumericPrompt("Enter your age:"));
var restingPulse = parseInt(requireNumericPrompt("Enter your resting heart rate:"));

document.write('Age: ' + age + '<br/>');
document.write('Resting pulse: ' + restingPulse + '<br/>');
for (var targetRate, i = 0.55; i < 1; i+=0.05){
  targetRate = (((220 - age) - restingPulse) * i) + restingPulse;
  document.write("Intensity: " + Math.round((i * 100)) + "% | Rate: " + Math.round(targetRate) + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Happy to be helpful (:

Comment: Note if they are actually expecting floats using /\d+$/ wont match as the float will be converted to a string and that pattern will not match the decimal

Answer (score 1):

At the point where where you test the regular expressions, those variables `age` and `restingPulse` are `undefined`. You'll have to move the code for testing to within the loop, *after* those variables have received values from user input:

```
while(!valid) {
  age = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your age:"));
  restingPulse = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your resting heart rate:"));

  numCheckAge = /^\d+$/.test(age);
  numCheckPulse = /^\d+$/.test(restingPulse);
  if(numCheckAge && numCheckPulse) {
    valid = true;
  } 
  else {
    alert("Sorry. That's not a valid input, please enter numbers.");
  }
}
```

Also, you can drop the `=== true` bits, and use the truth value of the variable directly for testing.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var age, restingPulse, targetRate, numCheckAge, numCheckPulse, valid;

valid = false;
numCheckAge =function(a) { 
 return /^\d+$/.test(a);
}
numCheckPulse = function(a){
 return /^\d+$/.test(restingPulse);
} 

while(valid === false) {
  age = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your age:"));
  restingPulse = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your resting heart rate:"));
  if(numCheckAge(age) && numCheckPulse(restingPulse)) {
    valid = true;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry. That's not a valid input, please enter numbers.");
  }
}

for (var i = 0.55; i < 1; i+=0.05){
  targetRate = (((220 - age) - restingPulse) * i) + restingPulse;
  document.write("Intensity: " + Math.round((i * 100)) + "% | Rate: " + Math.round(targetRate) + "<br>");
}
```

you need to convert your check code to a function instead a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track you just forgot to initialize the variable.

```js
var age, restingPulse, targetRate, numCheckAge, numCheckPulse, valid;

age = 0;
restingPulse = 0;

valid = false;
numCheckAge = /^\d+$/.test(age);
numCheckPulse = /^\d+$/.test(restingPulse);

while(valid !== true) {
    age = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your age:"));
    restingPulse = parseFloat(prompt("Enter your resting heart rate:"));
    if(numCheckAge === true && numCheckPulse === true) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        alert("Sorry. That's not a valid input, please enter numbers.");
    }
}

for (var i = 0.55; i < 1; i+=0.05){
    targetRate = (((220 - age) - restingPulse) * i) + restingPulse;
    document.write("Intensity: " + Math.round((i * 100)) + "% | Rate: " + Math.round(targetRate) + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Validating 0 values? Why?

Comment: cause with since you are mimicking OOP with JavaScript, unless the variable has static storage space, it's initial value is indeterminate.

Comment: ok. But how it will check entered data before if statement: `if(numCheckAge === true && numCheckPulse === true) {` ?